# how can i insert data to a textarea from database

Tags: php

I want to print `comment` column data in a textarea but i couldn't.

**my controller**

```
public function view_comment()
{
    $opno= $this->input->post('opno');
    $result['result_display']=$this->pat_model->get_comment($opno);   
    $this->load->view('home',$result);  
}
```

**my model**

```
public function get_comment($opno)
{
    $this->db->select('comment');
    $this->db->order_by('datecolumn','ASC');
    $this->db->where('opno',$opno);            
    $query= $this->db->get('history');
    return $query->result();
}
```

**my view page**

```
<textarea name="comment" id> 
<?php 

    foreach($result_display as $rec)
    { 
        echo "comment:"." ".$rec->comment."\n";  
    }

    ?>
</textarea>
```

how can i insert data to a textarea?

Comment: have your data comes to your view i mean `print_r($result_display);` what it return

Comment: you are passing $result to the view and calling $result_display, I am not familiar with codeigniter but it looks little inconsistent to me

Comment: still i can't find anything by using " print_r($result_display);"